# Need help on using random to get a random string from array

Tags: javascript

I already know how to pull random from an array but this won't work. Trying to make an HTML game.
I use Caret.
I'm pretty new to coding but know most of the basics.

```
function person() {
...
  interests = ["food", "clothes", "tech"]; //interest definition because I keep getting "undefined"
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); //random var
  instrestscho = interests[rand]; //interest random string puller that's not working
 ...
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you say it is not working?

Comment: Should be working. All I can contribute with is that you should replace `* 3` with `* interests.length` so you don't have to change that value every time the array changes. Also, in the example, you got one too many closing brackets (`}`).

Answer (score 1):

I spy an extra:

```
}
```

I'm guessing this is the error because everything else should work.

Also, if the point of this function is to grab a random interest, you may want to return it, like so:

```
function person() {
  interests = ["food", "clothes", "tech"]; //interests definition
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * interests.length); //random var
  return interests[rand]; //return interest random string
}
console.log( person() );
```

Comment: That other '}' is needed, i just put '...' so I don't put all the fluff in.

Comment: your problem might be in that other code then. it's not in this code.